# How to transfer form object's data from client from one server to another client

Tags: c#, tcp, system.net.sockets

I'd like to create checker on multiplayer. When I click on the button in form's client it sends request to the server and then the server sands data to another form's client. There is a client form.

[image]

I've checked a lot of tutorials on the web, but there are projects where they transfer only texts like chat communication between clients. I'd like to do when user click on the button the changing will appear in the another client. Do you know how to transfer data of the component object in the form to another on the network?

Comment: Look up WCF - Windows Communication Foundation

Comment: Oky thx, I'm going to do...

Comment: No use SignalR it's much better for this.

Comment: I think [this](https://thenappingkat.azurewebsites.net/tag/signalr/) is a good place to start